# Passing variable from ts to html as method parameter in Angular

Tags: angular

I have declared a variable in ts. Now in the html, I have a method that I call on an onclick event. What I want to do is concatenate a string with the variable in the ts as the method parameter. How do I achieve this?

ts:

```
testVariable: string = "Test";

testfunction(test: string){
....}
```

html:

```
<button (click)="testfunction(template...)">CLICK</button> //template here is just a random string
// The method parameter should be templateTest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly if this is what you want, but...  I give you 2 ways:

A) With Backtips (`)

```
<button (click)=`testfunction(template(${testVariable}))`>CLICK</button>
```

B) With string interpolation

```
<button (click)="testfunction(template({{testVariable}}))">CLICK</button>
```

Comment: The extra spaces were just to show the code easyly ( I edit it now and erase the extra space).   You hace edit your code, I put mine following your old code version.  Now, I don't know what you want to achieve. Ir order to get help, can you edit and give more info and some example, at the end of your first post, please?